# MySQL Workbench alter table after updating to Windows 11

Tags: mysql

I updated from Windows 10 to Windows 11. Now I can not alter any table anymore on MySQL Workbench.
I increased the timeout to 600 seconds, but still same error. My DB is quiet empty, so it should be no problem of size.
Do I have to change something in the configuration after updating to Win11 for MySQL Workbench?

I have a Python script, which is using this MySQL-DB to use some entries from this DB, that is still working.

I can not share error code as text, because of no copy-paste-functionality.

EDIT: I add the text a can be seen in the screenshot:

```
Error: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.

Executing:
ALTER TABLE 'map'.
ADD COLUMN `route_location` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `route_event`;

Operation failed: There was an error applying thee SQL script to the database.
ERROR 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `map`.`routepoints`
ADD COLUMN `route_location` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `route_event`
```

[image: SQL Error]

I tried it with SQL-Script and also with GUI.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Note that your query may still be running. Try `show full processlist`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220421/lost-connection-to-server-executing-alter-table#comment558999_220421) or any of the other comments on this question: [Lost connection to server executing ALTER TABLE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220421/lost-connection-to-server-executing-alter-table)

Comment: Can you try the same statement using the [MySQL command line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) ?  (Because the errors in MySQL workbench are .... not giving much info )

Comment: @Luuk thx for comment. I tried it with command client and the error "duplicate column" appeared. I checked afterwards in the table and saw, that now the column exists. Very strange behaviour. I tried now to add another column and it works without error. Strange, but thx for your time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved, and is based on the information mysql-workbench does NOT give, making it hard for a starting user to understand what is going on. 

Comment: @Luuk how can I close the question with just comments and no answer? or do I have to delete it?

Comment: 2 options: 1) provide an accepted answer   2) delete it.   3) leave it this way.... (oh, that's 3 options )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting MySQL-Workbench and several times of trying to rerun the SQL-Script it creates the column in the table. Since then I have no problem and its working properly, even if I add a new column.